# Local Storage using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, e-commerce, cart

I'm developing an e-commerce and I'm trying to set local storage to hold the elements inside the cart.

All fine when i add a product to the cart and all but once i refresh the cart page, all products just disappear.

I tried set the local storage and i can't figure where i'm wrong...

My browser is fine with local storage permissions (Edge).

cart.component.ts:

```
    export class CartComponent {

  products = this.cartService.getProducts();

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService
  ) { }


  totalPrice = this.cartService.getProducts().reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.PriceWithIVA, 0);




}
```

cart.service.ts:

```
  addToCart(product: ProductDTO) {
    this.products.push(product);

    let products = [];

    if (localStorage.getItem ('products')) {
        products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    }

    products.push ({
        name: product.Name,
        image: product.Attachment,
        price: product.PriceWithIVA
    })

    localStorage.setItem ('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    this.products = products;
}




getCartDetailsByUser() {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem ('products'));
    this.products = data;

    if (data !== null) {
        this.cartQuantity = data.length;
    }
}


getProducts() {
    return this.products;
}

clearCart() {
    localStorage.removeItem ('products');
    this.products = [];
    this.cartQuantity = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `getCartDetailsByUser()` called?

Comment: do you mean once you refresh it disappears from the localstorage or just from the service  this.products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In constructor of your service you should ask about "localStorage.getItem ('products')"

```
constructor(){
   const products=localStorage.getItem ('products')
   this.products=products?JSON.parse(products):[];
}
```

**Update***
@Jany, you need pay attention to the name of the variables -you store the data as name, price and image but when you add to cart received an object with but received Name, Attachment and PriceWithIVA.

Futhermore you has variable products in service and in your card, perhafs it's good use a getter.

I forked your code

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  totalPrice: number;

  //I use a getter
  get products() {
    return this.cartService.getProducts()
    //you also can use
    return this.cartService.products;
  }
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculeTotal();
  }

  add() {

    //well I add a "fool product"
    const date = new Date();
    this.cartService.addToCart({
      Name: 'fool ' + date.getSeconds(),
      PriceWithIVA: 100,
    });
    this.calculeTotal();
  }

  clear() {
    this.cartService.clearCart();
    this.calculeTotal();
  }

  //After any operation we should call to CalculateTotal

  private calculeTotal() {
    this.totalPrice = this.products.reduce(
      (acc, product) => acc + product.price,
      0
    );
  }
}
```

Your service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CartService {
  products: any[] = [];
  cartQuantity = 0;
  constructor() {
    //get the "localstorage"
    const local = localStorage.getItem('products');

    //if exist, use JSON.parse, else return an empty array
    const products = local ? JSON.parse(local) : [];

   //map to be sure the "price" is a number
    this.products = products.map((x: any) => ({
      ...x,
      price: +(x.price || 0),
    }));

   //really it's unnecesary
    this.cartQuantity = products ? products.length : 0;
  }
  addToCart(product: any) {
    this.products.push({
      name: product.Name,
      image: product.Attachment,
      price: +product.PriceWithIVA,
    });
    
    //but we need actualize the value of qauntity
    this.cartQuantity = products ? products.length : 0;

    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(this.products));
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this.products;
  }

  clearCart() {
    localStorage.removeItem('products');
    this.products = [];
    this.cartQuantity = 0;
  }
}
```

A [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vdee9?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: Thank you, i tried it but i have still the same problem...

Comment: @Jany, ::glups:: yes, I forget "parser" the localStorage. I just update the answer

Comment: Added the parse and now i can't access the cart page at all on the site lol i have to understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Jany, you need pay attention to the name of the variables, I update my answer, I hope can help you.

Comment: I'm still a junior with Angular and typescript so i have to study and understand your code before implementing in my projec. Thank you so much for your help, hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this instead which is way more clear code to add to your local storage.

```
addToCart(product: ProductDTO) {

  let products;

  if (localStorage.getItem ('products')) {
      products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
  } else {
      products = [];
  }

  products.push ({
      name: product.Name,
      image: product.Attachment,
      price: product.PriceWithIVA
  })

  localStorage.setItem ('products', JSON.stringify(products));
  this.products = products;
}
```

Also add the following to your component that holds the `this.products` to use the local storage each time the component loads.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, still the same problem...

Comment: @jany share your html template file as well